# Restar 1 hora al campo datetime en todos los querys a la vez sin intervenir la consulta

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Tengo varios querys select que muestran como resultado el campo datetime, ¿antes de enviar los querys se podrá enviar algún comando como por ejemplo "SET time_zone = '-01:00'" y despues enviar los query teniendo como resultado 1 hora menos? no se debe utilizar date_sub() o date_add() en el query mismo ya que no los quiero modificar uno a uno. ¿O tendré que modificar cada uno de los querys debido a que no es posible?. 
MySQL version 5.0 y 5.5, saludos.

Comment: Puedes hacerlo con offset desde UTC o por nombre de zona, ¿Cuál es la zona horaria del servidor y cuál es la que quieres?

Comment: Algo no huele bien en la pregunta. Me parece que estás tratando de solucionar un problema en el lugar incorrecto. ¿Por qué las fechas/horas están mal? ¿Cambiaste la zona horaria del servidor, almacenaste los datos mal, cuál es la raíz del problema?